# Pass a variable on HTML load with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form I'm loading via jquery .load and I'm wondering if it's possible to pass something on load to configure whether it should be disabled or not.

Here's and example of how I'm doing it now:

```
$("#someWrapper").load('somefile.html',function()
{
    if (someBoolean) 
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
           $(".someTable").prop("disabled",true);
        },1500);
    }       
});
```

But I would like to disable it on load not after if possible. Open to suggestions.

Comment: Use $.ajax, get the HTML and manipulate it before loading it into the DOM.

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout()`, change the property immediately.

Comment: On load, a table is loaded and this html doesn't exist until then. The timeout is approximating how long it takes so that the html can be updated after